# increment number that is insde the character

Tags: shell

I want to increment the number inside the string as follows.

```
param1
param2
param3
```

What I want to get is as below.

```
param1
param2
param3
param4
param5
...
param100
param101
```

How to achieve it easily?

Comment: are those literal dots? and how do the starting three items become 7, or 101?

Comment: This question, as it is currently written, is unclear. The expected output does not match the input and the question. If the input is three strings, then how is the output longer? Also, why did the first three strings in the output not increment, as the question asks for?

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** that's what you really want to do? You're creating a situation in which it will be difficult for you to use simple sorting to deal with the data. An alternative would be ask for the number to be zero-padded to some safe number of decimal places, `param00001` ... `param00999` ...

Comment: @user1404316 Difficult? I don't know the OP's system, but in 2018, natural sorting (`param10` comes *after* `param9`) should be omnipresent, I think. MacOS does it ever since, KDE supports it for long time, and on Linux you have GNU `ls` with `ls -v` which is my default. This zero-padding is an ugly mess, forcing people to think like computers did in the 1980ies. And it still fails as numbers grow bigger. I stopped this nonsense long ago and cleared the relationship to my devices: I'm the boss, they need to adapt to human thinking, not the other way around anymore.

Comment: @Philippos - So you're visually fine with the left-alignment of the numbers, wherein the digit columns don't have matching units, boss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for string in param{1..101}; do echo $string; done
```

This gives the desired output easily and hopefully fits your need. If not, you need to give some context what to do with those strings.